# Do I need an antenna tuner for new mobile antenna

Tags: antenna, antenna-system, impedance-matching, ht, mobile

I am looking to buy my first mobile antenna, for use with a 2m/70cm HT in the car.  The HT needs 50 Ω impedence.

I was looking at [this antenna](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00QJ27OY8), but another ham told me that I need 1/4 wave or 5/8 wave to get 50 Ω impedance.  A 1/2 wave antenna will not be 50 Ω so I will need to add an antenna tuner (or risk burning up the radio).

I'm confused - can someone enlighten me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The HT needs 50 ohm impedence.

An antenna of this kind should be designed to have a 50 ohm impedance (when properly installed on top of a ground plane such as a car roof). It probably won't be *exactly* 50 ohms across both bands, but that's fine as long as the difference (as measured in SWR) is not too high. Usually the trouble is if you're using an antenna *not* designed for that band.

> A 1/2 wave antenna will not be 50 ohm

This is either not a true 1/2 wave antenna (I see it has a loading coil in the middle) or the description is made of lies. 1/2 wave end-fed antennas require specialized matching networks. While this antenna's length is close to 1/2 wave, it also has a loading coil in the middle, which means its electrical behavior is not equal to that of a 1/2 wave wire.

[Comet's page](https://cometantenna.com/amateur-radio/mobile-antennas/ma-dual-band/) says this antenna should have a SWR of 1.5:1 or less across its bands. That's quite good for a mobile antenna.

> so I will need to add an antenna tuner

As a general rule, antenna tuners — adjustable impedance-matching networks — are **not used for VHF/UHF antenna systems**. This is because antenna tuners are needed when you want to use *one* antenna across *different bands and wide bands*, or to use an improvised antenna whose exact length and coupling to the environment are unpredictable (for portable operation). Both of these are activities are common on the **HF** bands (including up to 50 MHz, which is where HF and VHF techniques and antenna designs start to cross over). But for VHF/UHF, it works quite well to design one antenna that is a reasonable compromise across the entirety of those two bands.

For a new mobile installation, the best option is to obtain the use of an *antenna analyzer,* which can tell you not only what the SWR is across the bands, but also where the antenna's resonant peaks are — allowing adjustment if the antenna provides any room for adjustment. (For example, my VHF antenna came with a slightly long wire element, to be cut down to length after testing.)

But you will almost certainly not *need* to do that. The antenna is probably just fine as provided, as long as it's installed per the instructions.

> (or risk burning up the radio).

HTs are designed to survive being used with a wide range of antenna impedances. This is necessary, because they are designed to be used hand-held in a wide variety of positions, and all the objects around them will affect the antenna impedance. The stock “rubber ducky” antennas they come with are often far from 50 Ω even in perfect conditions.

You would want to take more care with a higher power mobile radio installed in the car, such as checking with an antenna analyzer. Even then, it is unlikely that the radio would be damaged — modern radios have protection circuits to prevent the final amplifier from overheating.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with most of the previous answers. A mobile antenna is designed to give 50 ohms at the feedpoint by having a loading coil, or inductor, at the base of the antenna. And generally the only way to match a short vertical antenna is to physically change the length of the antenna. Usually mobile type antenna whips are a bit long and the only way to get a good match is to cut a small bit off the base of the whip and check. But any radio should be able to deal with a slight mismatch as mobile communications tend to be short so won't produce smoke.